# Missing argument 1 for _e()

Tags: php, error-handling

I get this error:
Missing argument 1 for _e(), called in ... on line 14 and defined in ... on line 246.
I don't know what happened. Can anyone help me to fix this?

This is the php code:

```
<?php
                if( have_posts () ){
                    ?><h2 ><span><?php _e(); echo  single_cat_title() ; ?></span></h2><?php
                }else{
                    ?><h2 ><span><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts found' , 'cosmotheme' ); ?></span></h2><?php
                }
            ?>
```

Line 14 is:  `?><h2 ><span><?php _e(); echo  single_cat_title() ; ?></span></h2><?php`

And this is the line 246:

```
function _e( $text, $domain = 'default' ) {
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 14, you're calling `_e();` without any arguments. The function definition **requires** the `$text` argument. That means you can't call `_e()` without any arguments.

Comment: I am using a wordpress theme. I didn't do anything from my own.

Comment: Can you help me solve this? Thanks anyway for your answer.

Comment: Is there any code I need to write in the Index file?

Comment: On line 14, remove the call to `_e();`. Without arguments, it's not doing anything anyway. Maybe contact the theme developer so they can fix it as well.

Comment: Thank you very much. Problem solved. I deleted that code and now everything is ok.